# How to get next node after parent of current via symfony crawler?

Tags: php, html, dom, web-crawler, symfony

Example HTML 5 for parsing:

```
<div id="orderDetails">
    <div> ... any number of blocks with unnecessary stuff ... </div>
    <div>Label for important info</div>
    <table> ... some other block type ... </table>
    <div>Some very important info here</div>
    <div> ... any number of blocks with unnecessary stuff ... </div>
</div>
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler($html);
$label = $crawler->filter('#orderDetails div:contains("Label for important info")');
$info = $label->parent()->next('div');
assert('Some very important info here' === $info->text(), 'Important info must be grabbed from HTML');
```

But unfortunately crawler has no methods `parent` and `next`. But.. it has `parents` that gives me *all* parent nodes == all div's that i cannot differ.

So i have two questions in this case:

1. How to get parent of current node? Not all nodes but "actual" one!
2. How to traverse dom horizontally with some analogue of `next`/`prev`?

Thanks.

Comment: I notice [the API mentions](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_parents) `parents()` "Returns the parents of the current selection". I'm not sure if that's helpful for you?

Comment: Yeah, i saw this, but i need only "current parent, not parent**s**" and "only one next node, not **all** of them".
However, after reading sources (with aim to reinvent wheel) i've found that it's just names of methods are very confusing (see my answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Story

After some digging into source code, i've found that method `nextAll()` returns not "all" but just "one" node (`$node = $this->getNode(0);`).

That means if i need "two nodes after current", then i must write `$node->nextAll()->nextAll()->nextAll()`.

WTF?! This is super strange naming convention (0_0).

### Answers

> 1. How to get parent of current node? Not all nodes but "actual" one!

```
// This is only one parent node
$parent = $node->parents();
```

> 2. How to traverse dom horizontally with some analogue of next/prev?

```
// This is only one node – next after current
$next = $node->nextAll();
// This is only one node – previous before current
$prev = $node->nextAll();
// This is only one node – next after two from current
$nextAfterTwo = $node->nextAll()->nextAll()->nextAll();
```

### Concrete code solution

So, as needed implementation really exists, function-solution to question looks like this:

```
/**
 * Returns sibling node that is after current and filtered with selector
 *
 * @param Crawler $start    Node from which start traverse
 * @param string  $selector CSS/XPath selector like in `Crawler::filter($selector)`
 *
 * @return Crawler Found node wrapped with Crawler
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When node not found
 */
function getNextFiltered(Crawler $start, string $selector) : Crawler
{
    $count = $start->parents()->count();
    $next  = $start->nextAll();
    while ($count --> 0) {
        $filtered = $next->filter($selector);
        if ($filtered->count()) return $filtered;
        $next = $next->nextAll();
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('No node found');
}
```

And in my example:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$label   = $crawler->filter('#orderDetails div:contains("Label for important info")');
$info    = getNextFiltered($label, 'div');
assert('Some very important info here' === $info->text(), 'Important info must be grabbed from HTML');
```

Comment: If (for example) you need the third node after the current one, you can just do `$node->nextAll()->eq(2)`. This means that `$node->nextAll()` will produce the same result as `$node->nextAll()->eq(0)` which gets the next node after the current one.